# How to Store Data Sent back using the delegate method?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, store

I have data sent back to my VC using the delegate method. How can I possibly store it so then I can use it to send to another VC?

```
func DataToPass(ArrayName: [String]) { //function from delegate
    Datacollect = ArrayName
    print(ArrayName)
}
```

Here's the function used in the delegate method that holds my data. `ArrayName` is an array containing my data. 
`Datacollect` is an attempt to collect it, however nothing gets stored in `Datacollect`.

I have already assigned `Datacollect` as a `String` array.

```
var Datacollect = [String]()
```

How can I store the data to my VC from `ArrayName`?

Comment: Do I use a completion?

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways of storing data and one of the simplest ways to get started is to use the built-in UserDefaults.

This is how you might use the following code inside a method to store your DataCollect array.

```
Let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(DataCollect, forKey: "DataCollect")
```

To retrieve the data you could use the following code inside a method:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let DataCollect = defaults.array(forkey: "DataCollect")
```

Comment: Ive used  `let DCollect=ArrayName` `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard` `defaults.set(DCollect, forKey: "DCollect")` to store my data, and `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard` `let DCollect = String(describing: defaults.array(forKey: "DCollect"))` to present it. And then the output of DCollect is `optional([collected data])`   how can I get rid of the optional?

Comment: It's correct that it is an optional - there may not be any data stored in that key.
There are a couple of ways to handle this but I would recommend reassigning to another variable (of the same name is good) and this will unwrap the variable.  
So we have 

    defaults = UserDefaults.standard // this is optional
    if let defaults=defaults {
    //defaults is unwrapped (no longer optional) so go wild!
    //code here
    }

Sorry about the formatting - seems difficult to get this right in the comments